# Use Flycheck over Tramp

Tags: tramp, flycheck, ssh, clang

I have a running docker containing simple C source file makefile and compile_commands file generated by bear. What I want to do is to make Flycheck-clangcheck lint my C code on the fly.
However when I give command flycheck-compile and choose the clangcheck  the shell output looks as following:
error: no such file or directory: '/ssh:....
From that I assume that clang-check command was trying to find the file locally with the name that Tramp constructed .The buffer-file-name variable shows up the long name started with /ssh:... and I wonder is there any way to map remote file name to local one so that the shell command can respect it without errors? Or any ways to integrate Flycheck with Tramp?

Answer (score 0):

Flycheck uses `call-process` and `start-process`, which are agnostic to remote processes. I recommend to file a bug report for flycheck in order to change this.